# Git pull suggests bogus conflicts

Tags: git, pull

I have created a fork of a project "theirs", called "mine".
Now I have added several new files to mine, without editing any existing files. Meanwhile theirs was updated to a newer version. Now when I do a "git pull ", it suggests a lot of merge conflicts in files that I added. Somehow git is showing me different versions of my own code, rather than comparing their and my code, which can definitely not have any conflicts.

What am I missing here? Going through the hundreds of commits by hand is clearly not a good option...

**Updates:**

- What is the output from git remote -v

  theirs  their-url (fetch)
  theirs  their-url (push)
  origin  my-url (fetch)
  origin  my-url (push)
- Have you submitted any pull requests that have been accepted?
  Nope
- Verify if there are files with the same names.
  No, they are not. One file in conflict is "matlab/imdb/ImdbCalvin.m". That is a file which I created and it's certainly not present in the remote repo (see https://github.com/vlfeat/matconvnet/tree/master/matlab ).

Comment: Can you provide some sample output? Particularly what is the exact command? Also, what are the remote settings (i.e. what is the output from `git remote -v`?)

Comment: Since you forked, have you submitted any pull requests that have been accepted?

Comment: Fetch theirs state into a local branch without pulling or merging, check it out and verify if there are files with the same names.

Comment: I updated the original post to answer your questions..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Somehow git is showing me different versions of my own code

Make sure you have pushed your commits to your remote with `git push origin`, then pull from upstream with `git pull upstream` (assuming your `theirs` is actually named as `upstream`)